# C Program to list Armstrong Numbers upto 1000

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

    void main()
    {
         int i , n , sum=0, rem;
         clrscr();
        for(i=1;i<=1000;i++)
         {
           while(i!=0)
           {
             rem = i%10;
             sum = sum + pow(rem,3);
             i = i / 10;
           } 
           if(i == sum)
           printf("\n %d", i);
         }
         getch();
    }
```

I tried the above code for printing Armstrong Numbers upto 1000 . The output that I got was a list of zeros. I am not able to find the error in the code. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the answer helped, please don't forget to accept the answer. See how to accept an answer ---> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

You should keep a copy of i, so that it could be kept for comparison with the sum variable.

As of now, you compare sum and i, at every step when i has become 0.

You should use a temp variable to store value of i(before performing i/=10).

Also, you can't keep i in the while-loop as it would always be 0, and hence post increment will have no effect on it. You should need another temporary variable, say `div`.

And, you should finally print `temp`.

Also, an Armstrong number is an n-digit number that is equal to the sum of the nth powers of its digits.

So, for 1000, you need to caclculate the 4th power.

```
int temp,div;
for(i=1;i<=1000;i++)
     {
       temp = i;
       div = i;
       while(div!=0)
       {
         rem = div%10;
         sum = sum + pow(rem,3);
         div = div / 10;
       } 
       if(temp == sum)
       printf("\n %d", temp);
     }
```

NOTE :- Probably you're using Turbo C compiler(check that header `<conio.h>`), which you shouldn't(you should avoid it). You should use GCC(on Linux system), CodeBlocks IDE(on Windows).

Comment: Also the 1000 is of 4 digits so OP must change the pow(rem,3) to pow(rem,4)

Comment: No @Am_I_Helpful, Armstrong number is a number which is equal to sum of digits raise to the power total number of digits in the number

Comment: yeah .. got it ! the value of i should be preserved. but even then we are printing i , which is already 0 . so the problem remains

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful You can't use `i` in the `while` loop. The `for` loop is trying to increment `i`, but the `while` loop is always driving `i` back to 0. That can't end well.

Comment: `GCC(on Linux system), CodeBlocks IDE(on Windows)` Just to nitpick: GCC is a compiler, CB an IDE, different things. CB on Windows also uses GCC as compiler, and you can also use CB on Linux !

Comment: @kebs - Thanks for hinting that for OP, but it was for OP to understand without confusion. I know GCC is a compiler; and CodeBlocks uses MinGW(which is a minimalist GNU compiler). But, only for more clarity I left that for OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code to print Armstrong number in given range.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
   {
    int num,r,sum,temp;
    int min,max;

    printf("Enter the minimum range: ");
    scanf("%d",&min);

    printf("Enter the maximum range: ");
    scanf("%d",&max);

    printf("Armstrong numbers in given range are: ");
    for(num=min;num<=max;num++)
       {
         temp=num;
         sum = 0;

         while(temp!=0)
             {
               r=temp%10;
               temp=temp/10;
               sum=sum+(r*r*r);
             }
         if(sum==num)
             printf("%d ",num);
       }
     return 0;
  }
```